# How to perform auto click on command button in jsf using script

Tags: javascript, jsf, oracle-adf

i have  a situation where i have to execute a commandButton action listener on page load in following JSF page

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
         xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
         xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html">
        <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

        <f:view>

       <af:document id="d1" partialTriggers="pt1">
       <af:resource type="javascript">  
       function callCustomButton(){
       var button =AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId("cbCustomFields");
       ActionEvent.queue(button,true);
       }
       </af:resource>



     <af:clientListener method="callCustomButton" type="load"/>

      <af:form id="f1">
     <af:pageTemplate viewId="/ESOPM_Base_Template.jspx" id="pt1">



    <f:facet name="main_content">

    <af:decorativeBox id="db1" theme="medium">
        <f:facet name="top"/>
        <f:facet name="center">
        <af:panelGroupLayout layout="scroll" id="pgl2"> 
        <trh:tableLayout id="tblUpload" cellPadding="3" cellSpacing="3"  halign="center" inlineStyle="font-size:1.2em; font-weight:bold; font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <trh:rowLayout id="rl1">

                    <trh:cellFormat id="cf1">            
                        <af:panelGroupLayout layout="horizontal" id="pgl3">

                   <af:commandButton text="Custom Fields"                       

                  actionListener="#{EditProperties.generateCustomAttributeFields}" 
                  id="cbCustomFields"  partialSubmit="true"  visible="true"/>
                        </af:panelGroupLayout>
                    </trh:cellFormat>
                </trh:rowLayout>

                  </trh:cellFormat>
              </trh:rowLayout>

        </trh:tableLayout>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
        </f:facet>
        </af:decorativeBox>
        </f:facet>
</af:pageTemplate>
</af:form>
</af:document>
</f:view>

</jsp:root>
```

The command button is "Custom Fields" and i m trying to call it by the javascript i have used in the page through the client Listener.
But when a user load this page the button does not get clicked and the its action listener operation is not performed.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Is this adf-stuff JSF 2? If so you can execute something server-side on page load by using a preRenderViewlistener:

```
<f:view>
    <f:metadata>
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.doSomething}"/>
    </f:metadata>
</f:view>
```

**Update**

Another approach is to make your backing bean request scoped and use the @PostConstruct Annotation for initializing data:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init (){

    }  
}
```

And if you have the chance to switch to another JSF component lib, i would recommend Primefaces. They provide a very simple solution for executing backing bean methods by client side script. See `<p:remoteCommand>` on [https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf).

Answer (score 1):

create an afterMethod in f:view (managed bean) and listen for the RENDER_RESPONSE phase. Then invoke JS by a call to

```
String script = "callCustomButton();";
FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
//Trinidad class
ExtendedRenderKitService erks = null;  
//Service also is a Trinidad class
erks = Service.getRenderKitService(fctx, ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
erks.addScript(fctx, script);
```

Make sure you avoid double invocation by setting a memory flag in view scope

Frank
P.s. Have you tried invoking that function on the server queuing an action event in a managed bean (listener)